# how to separate data files from the journal? mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am not able to separate the data files from the journal (in different drives); if I change the path, the journal will also go to that same path.

Any help?

Comment: Please see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56337/how-to-separate-mongodb-journal for a possible workaround

Comment: Thanks for your answer! the process described seems to be for linux; not sure if this can be achieved on Windows...